# Latent class clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

I have data that contains continuous and categorical variables and I have to cluster that data using latent class analaysis - LCA. I know that LCA sometimes mean that manifest variables are categorical but I read that programs like LatentGold know how to hande both types of data when clustering this way. Do you know how to do that kind of clustering in R? Is there any package that can help me with that? I looked over a lot of packages like poLCA, MCLUST but I didn't manage to do what I want. 
Thanks